# How do I re-run Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I see this on the Github web UI:

[image: screenshot]

but it's not clear to me whether the disabled re-runs are a result of my `.github/main.workflow` configuration, or inherited from the Github Actions service.

Sample workflow below - I don't see anything obvious there that would disable re-runs.

```
workflow "Test, Lint" {
  on = "push"
  resolves = [
    "Test",
    "Lint",
    "Lint Format"
  ]
}

action "Install" {
  uses = "actions/npm@master"
  args = "install"
  secrets = ["SECRET_TOKEN"]
}

action "Test" {
  needs = "Install"
  uses = "actions/npm@master"
  args = "test"
  secrets = ["SECRET_TOKEN"]
}

action "Lint" {
  needs = "Install"
  uses = "actions/npm@master"
  args = "run lint"
  secrets = ["SECRET_TOKEN"]
}

action "Lint Format" {
  needs = "Install"
  uses = "actions/npm@master"
  args = "run lint:format"
  secrets = ["SECRET_TOKEN"]
}
```

Comment: If the build is for a PR branch, and you’ve had subsequent changes on the main branch, then you can rebase the PR branch locally and push it to back to your GitHub remote branch. Or even if you’ve not had subsequent changes on the main branch, you can locally amend the latest commit message on the branch — by making a minor whitespace or punctuation change or something — and then push back to your GitHub remote branch.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are two situations:

1. **On a failed build**, from the [docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/managing-a-workflow-run#viewing-your-workflow-history)

> Optionally, if the run failed, to re-run the workflow, in the upper-right corner of the workflow, use the **Re-run checks** drop-down menu, and select **Re-run all checks**.
> [image: rerun]

2. **If your run did not fail**, you have to trigger the event which your workflow runs `on:` .

   In the most usual case of `on: push`, you can add an empty commit to poke GitHub actions:

   ```
   git commit --allow-empty -m "trigger GitHub actions"
   git push
   ```

   This will add an empty commit (no files changed), and will trigger another `push` event on GitHub, and therefore trigger another workflow run.

   This does, however, muck up the commit history.
   You can later squash/remove these if you like, but it's perhaps not ideal.

---

This is an update to my original answer, which referred to GitHub Actions HCL-based v1, prior to the August 2019 YAML-based re-release.
@tuff got this right first, with @instantepiphany‘s caveat.

Comment: I think there is also another way to re-run. It is by using `Deployment`.

set deployment on workflow.yml
---
name: test name
on: [deployment, push]
...

Then call curl like that
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -d '{"ref": "master", "environment": "periodic execution"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${reponame}/deployments

Comment: As an alternative for case #2 in this answer (pushing an empty commit), you could also locally amend the latest commit message on the branch — by making a minor whitespace or punctuation change or something — and then push back to your GitHub remote branch.

Comment: I posted another case user can trigger a re-run below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76918078/8175165

Answer (score 12):

You can also now (January 2020) use the new **[GitHub Actions API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/)**(!, still beta though), as [announced here](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-27-github-actions-api-beta/).

And it does include a [GitHub Actions Secrets API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow_runs/#re-run-a-workflow):

> ### Re-run a workflow
>
> Re-runs your workflow run using its id.
> Anyone with write access to the repository can use this endpoint.
> GitHub Apps must have the actions permission to use this endpoint.
>
> ```
> POST /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/runs/:run_id/rerun
> ```

So you can try and script and get an Actions workflow rerun through this new API.

---

[ken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2701130/ken) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435547/how-do-i-re-run-github-actions/59939257?noredirect=1#comment128630573_59939257) (July 2022):

> Only able to re-run a workflow ran within a month.
> Any workflow ran on more than 30 days cannot be re-run.
> Tested it Jun 2022.

---

Since July 2022, you can [differente triggering actor from executing actor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73046185/6309).

Comment: Nice try, however it disallows re-running a successful run. The error message that I receive:

`{
  "message": "This workflow run cannot be rerun",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow_runs/#re-run-a-workflow"
}`

Comment: @warpech That... unfortunate.

Comment: May be this API not works as documented. i get this error message `This workflow run cannot be rerun`

Comment: @SourovRoyChowdhury Was is a job with a prior successful run? As commented above, you cannot  re-run a successful run.

Comment: Only able to re-run a workflow ran within a month. Any workflow ran on more than 30 days cannot be re-run. tested it Jun 2022.

Comment: @ken That is... unfortunate. I have included your comment in the answer for  more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that your workflow starts on any push (your yml includes a trigger `on: [push]`), to re-run a successful action triggered by a commit, it is enough add a new liteweight tag.

I use this one liner to create a tag, push the tag, delete the tag, push the tag deletion:

```
git tag tmp-rerun && git push --tags && git tag -d tmp-rerun && git push origin :tmp-rerun
```

Answer (score 6):

This was just a missing/unimplemented feature of Github Actions, which has now been added. I didn't make any changes to my workflow file or repo settings, but I can now see UI to "Re-run all checks":

[image: screenshot of re-run ui]

(I got to this page by following the "Details" link from the checks section on my PR).

Comment: Unfortunately Actions can (as of this comment being posted) only be rerun if they have failed - at least in my team's repository, we can re run failed actions but that link/button isn't visible on successful actions, meaning we have to push an empty commit. For now that keeps us on Travis, although we want to switch to Actions as they are more powerful than Travis in other ways.

I would be suprised if GitHub didn't add this for feature parity - Travis supports rerunning successful builds, and so does BitBucket Pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

I made a python script to trigger the github workflows:

```
from github import Github

# using an access token : https://github.com/settings/tokens
g = Github("access_token")
#g = Github(base_url="https://{hostname}/api/v3", login_or_token="access_token")


for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    if (repo.get_workflows().totalCount > 0):
        print(repo.name, 'Have github workflow')
        for workflow in repo.get_workflows():
            if workflow.create_dispatch(repo.default_branch) is True:
                print(repo.name, 'Manual workflow has been trigger')
            else:
                print(repo.name, 'No nanual workflow, you need to add "workflow_dispatch:" to workflow file')
    else:
        print(repo.name, 'Does not have github workflow')
```

You need to install this: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub

Answer (score -1):

In case some one search 'GitHub Action re-run' and read this topic, I noticed GitHub now allow every job to re-run by clicking the re-run icon on the right of the job name.

[image: GitHub Action re-run job]

You can click the re-run icon and trigger again.

This is useful in some cases, for example, you can predefine a repo variable to let the specific job skipped, and when the condition match, you can update the variable and re-run that job.