# Make sure some github action only run by the owner

Tags: github-actions

I have an action job which upload the context to other website. The token was set and stored in the `secret.MY_TOKEN`.

But others who make the pull request also trigger this action job using the token I set.

How to limit the privilege of executing the jobs that only I can run this action job.

fyi my `ci.yml` as follow:

```yaml
name: foobar

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    ....

    - name: execute upload
      env:
        TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MYTOKEN }}
      run:
        upl --token ${TOKEN}
```

I assume there are two security problems here.

1. The token is printed in log file.
2. others who can use this private token by trigger action with their own purpose.

Comment: More information. I find push event can use the stored secrets variables. But pull_request not. Any documentation list the privilege information about this? Thx.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957218/what-is-the-difference-between-pull-request-and-pull-request-target-event-in-git and https://nathandavison.com/blog/github-actions-and-the-threat-of-malicious-pull-requests

Answer (score 3):

Use the *github.repository_owner* context

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context

The syntax should be something like:

```
- if: github.repository_owner == 'owner_name'
```

Comment: What would prevent someone from removing that line in a PR?

Comment: @Doryx, restricting PR merges to owners of the repo and requiring a review by owner for all PR merges might help prevent that

Comment: @sumit That's true, but won't the action start when the PR is created? I know we can review it pre-merge, but if they have already contributed to the repo, then it will fire off once they submit it.

Comment: hmm that might depend on the type of action.. Actions can also be restricted based on branch they are on for example:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
```

would restrict it to run only for PRs to the main branch..

 and for workflow dispatch actions, we can add another check: `if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}` to the jobs to make sure that it only runs from the main branch.

Answer (score 2):

When using `on: pull_request`, the workflow will not have any access to secrets.

There is a different trigger `on: pull_request_target` that will grant access to the secrets, but will use the workflow defined in the target branch.

See also:

- [GitHub Actions and the threat of malicious pull requests](https://nathandavison.com/blog/github-actions-and-the-threat-of-malicious-pull-requests)
- [What is the difference between pull_request and pull_request_target event in GitHubActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957218/what-is-the-difference-between-pull-request-and-pull-request-target-event-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe allowing actions to run only for certain users is a native feature.

However, you could simply check the action context actor and exit early if the actor is not the yourself (or the owner of the repo, or whatever condition you'd like).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature which could help, since July 2022:

> ### [Differentiating triggering actor from executing actor](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-07-19-differentiating-triggering-actor-from-executing-actor/)
>
> Starting next week, workflow re-runs in GitHub Actions will use the initial run’s actor for privilege evaluation.
> The actor who triggered the re-run will continue to be displayed in the UI, and can be accessed in a workflow via the `triggering_actor` field in the GitHub context.
>
> Currently, the privileges (e.g. – secrets, permissions) of a run are derived from the triggering actor.
> This poses a challenge in situations where the actor triggering a re-run is different than the original executing actor.
>
> **The upcoming change will differentiate the initial executing actor from the triggering actor, enabling the stable execution of re-runs**.
>
> For more details see **[Re-running workflows and jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs)**.