# What is the difference between pull_request and pull_request_target event in GitHubActions

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

What is the difference between `pull_request` and `pull_request_target` event in [GitHubActions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions)?

I found [this explanation in the GitHubActions Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target):

> This event (pull_request_target) runs in the context of the base of
> the pull request, rather than in the context of the merge commit, as
> the pull_request event does.

But, I can't understand what the context in githubAction is. Can anybody explain it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is summarized in "**[Github Actions and the threat of malicious pull requests](https://nathandavison.com/blog/github-actions-and-the-threat-of-malicious-pull-requests)**" by **[Nathan Davison](https://nathandavison.com/contact)**:

> When Github first launched Actions in 2018, this was not the case (or at least, [it wasn't intended to be](https://When%20Github%20first%20launched%20Actions%20in%202018,%20this%20was%20not%20the%20case%20(or%20at%20least,%20it%20wasn%27t%20intended%20to%20be)%20-%20in%20Actions%20terminology,%20the%20pull_request%20event%20and%20its%20variants%20were%20the%20only%20events%20that%20triggered%20on%20a%20PR%20being%20opened%20from%20a%20fork,%20and%20these%20events%20were%20made%20to%20not%20have%20access%20to%20repo%20secrets,%20including%20having%20access%20to%20a%20GITHUB_TOKEN%20value%20that%20is%20read-only.%20However,%20sometime%20later,%20in%20August%202020,%20the%20pull_request_target%20event%20was%20added.%20This%20event%20is%20given%20repo%20secrets%20and%20a%20full%20read/write%20GITHUB_TOKEN%20to%20boot,%20however%20there%20is%20a%20catch%20-%20this%20action%20only%20runs%20in%20the%20pull%20request%27s%20target%20branch,%20and%20not%20the%20pull%20request%27s%20branch%20itself.%20This%20differs%20from%20the%20CircleCI%20approach,%20which%20happily%20checked%20out%20the%20pull%20request%27s%20code%20when%20it%20was%20instructed%20to%20share%20secrets%20with%20PRs%20from%20forked%20repositories,%20including%20the%20pipeline%20configuration%20in%20the%20pull%20request.)) - in Actions terminology, the `pull_request` event and its variants were the only events that triggered on a PR being opened from a fork, and these events were made to not have access to repo secrets, including having access to a `GITHUB_TOKEN` value that is read-only.
>
> However, sometime later, in August 2020, [the `pull_request_target` event was added](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/).
>
> This event is given repo secrets and a full read/write `GITHUB_TOKEN` to boot, however there is a catch - this action only runs in the pull request's *target* branch, and not the pull request's branch itself.
>
> This differs from the CircleCI approach, which happily checked out the pull request's code when it was instructed to share secrets with PRs from forked repositories, including the pipeline configuration in the pull request (that would allow pull requests to be submitted just to steal tokens and secrets stored within the settings of a CircleCI project).

The [blog post](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/) confirms:

> In order to protect public repositories for malicious users we run all pull request workflows raised from repository forks with a read-only token and no access to secrets.
> This makes common workflows like labeling or commenting on pull requests very difficult.
>
> In order to solve this, we’ve added a new `pull_request_target` event, which behaves in an almost identical way to the `pull_request` event with the same set of filters and payload.
>
> However, instead of running against the workflow and code from the merge commit, the event runs against the workflow and code from the base of the pull request.
>
> This means the workflow is running from a trusted source and is given access to a read/write token as well as secrets enabling the maintainer to safely comment on or label a pull request.
> This event can be used in combination with the private repository settings as well.

---

> Is [**`pull_request_target`**](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) safe to use?

The `pull_request_target` event grants workflows triggered by pull requests from forks access to repository secrets and a read/write `GITHUB_TOKEN`. That is inherently risky if the workflow inadvertently exposes these secrets or allows for unauthorized modifications to the repository.

Another risk: the workflow attempts to check out and execute code from the pull request. Since this event runs in the context of the target branch with access to secrets, executing code from the PR without strict controls can expose secrets to untrusted code.

So it is best to:

- only use `pull_request_target` for workflows where access to secrets or write permissions is strictly necessary, such as commenting, labeling, or status updates on pull requests.
- have mechanisms in place to review or sandbox the code before execution if you must use `pull_request_target` and need to interact with the code from the pull request:  only run certain actions after manual approval via pull request reviews.
- implement conditional logic within your workflows to make sure steps requiring secrets or write permissions are only executed under safe conditions.
- explicitly specify the commit or branch you trust instead of checking out the PR's head commit blindly, when your workflow requires checking out code.

Other best practices: "[Keeping your GitHub Actions and workflows secure Part 1: Preventing pwn requests](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/)" by [Jaroslav Lobačevski](https://github.com/jarlob).

Comment: Is pull_request_target safe to use?

Comment: @s2t2 There are best practices to follow. I have edited the answer to address those.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is:

Given that Alice has a repo `foo` (alice/foo) and Bob forked `foo` from Alice (bob/foo).

Now Bob sends a pull request to Alice to foo for enhancement.

If you used `on: pull_request`, then the workflow runs the code defined by `bob/foo` but also having access to `alice/foo`.

In other word, **Bob used Alice's resources to run his workflow code** which is an absolute no-go as that means he could steal Alice's credentials with his own malicious workflow definitions.

But if you used `on: pull_request_target`, then the workflow runs on the code only existed on `alice/foo` **and so Bob can't hack Alice**, given Alice was competent enough to not let any malicious workflow code passed the code review.

However, if Bob is legit, this also added extra burden on him who really wanted to test his code with the official setup on Alice's workflow, say like getting a special dependency to build his artifacts from Alice's Maven/Nuget package repository of whom Bob doesn't have access to (so he can't test it locally), or Bob wants to have a dev Docker image released on Alice's repo instead, assuming some base image is only accessible from Alice and `alice/foo`. (again, this scenario may sound dumb and novel at first, but is practically very common on large projects with private dependencies)

So, most people just use a compromise, which is still use `on: pull_request`, but instead of letting you run right away, the contributors will need to do several code reviews and minimum amount of LGTMs first.

Comment: Bob is not given any tokens from Alice at `on: pull_request`. All tokens are empty.